# Chrome/Chromium Remote Debugging - Inspect Blank Pages

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

When I try to inspect a cordova app in development or even a browser tab I get a blank page. I have tried several Android devices. This was working two weeks ago just fine. I haven't manually updated the browsers, but I checked to make sure they are up to date. It is happening on both Chromium and Chrome.

I used <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to launch the inspector and I have two errors:

- > inspector.js:7949 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
- > VM99:72 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addExtensions' of undefined

I have tried several things. I uninstalled the browsers and reinstalled. I deleted all cache, history, etc. I deleted all entries for Local Storage and reset permissions on all devices. I also used `adb kill-server` and `adb -start-server`.

Any thoughts? Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you added some plugin with error, or need to insert it in onDeviceReady function